# Formatting string with %@ in Swift

Tags: swift, formatting

I have the following class with private struct for strings which I would like to use them for formatted strings later on. However, the code crashes at run time.

Why is this? Is it because it is defined as static let?

Below is the stripped code:

```
class LGNotificationHandler {
    private struct Strings {
        static let SentImagesENG = "Sent %@ images to the event"
        static let SentImagesTUR = "Etkinliğe %@ görsel gönderdi"
    }

    func buildNotificationString(imageCount: Int) -> String {
        if imageCount == 1 {
        .
        .
        .

        } else {
            // below line is giving error at run time
            notificationENG = String(format: Strings.SentImagesENG, imageCount)  
            notificationTUR = String(format: Strings.SentImagesTUR, imageCount)  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line causes the crash? What is the error message from the crash?

Comment: the line starting with 'notificationENG = ' gives error. I mention this in the comment at the end of the line. I will put it above the line for better visibility. The error I get is Thread 20: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x2)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You neglected to provide any details about the crash but one obvious problem is the use of the `%@` format specifier with an `Int`. You need to use `%d` with `Int`.

Comment: Actually, `%@` is for objects, not just text. You can find details about all of the format specifiers in the documentation. Look at the docs for `NSString stringWithFormat:` for a link.

Comment: Actually, here's the link: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265

Answer (score 20):

You need to replace **%@** with **%d**. ImageCount is `Int` value. so use *%d* instead of **%@**.

Format specifier:

```
%d - int Value 
%f - float value
%ld - long value
%@ - string value and for many more.
```

For see all Format Specifiers see Apple Doc [Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)

Answer (score 9):

**Update**
Shorter version

```
extension String {

    func format(_ arguments: CVarArg...) -> String {
        let args = arguments.map { String(describing: $0) } as [CVarArg]
        return String.init(format: self, arguments: args)
    }

}
```

You can use this extension

**Swift 5**

```
extension String {

    func format(_ arguments: CVarArg...) -> String {
        let args = arguments.map {
            if let arg = $0 as? Int { return String(arg) }
            if let arg = $0 as? Float { return String(arg) }
            if let arg = $0 as? Double { return String(arg) }
            if let arg = $0 as? Int64 { return String(arg) }
            if let arg = $0 as? String { return String(arg) }
            if let arg = $0 as? Character { return String(arg) }

            return "(null)"
        } as [CVarArg]

        return String.init(format: self, arguments: args)
    }

}
```

Using:

```
let txt = "My name is %@, I am %@ years old".format("Mickael", 24)
```

Comment: I get Cast from 'CVarArg' to unrelated type 'Character' always fails

Comment: It makes little sense to force every data type into a string just so the format string can only use `%@`. This loses all of the power of format specifiers. What if I want to format a Double with 3 decimal places? What if I want an Int forced to 2 digits with a leading 0 if needed? Also, this code will likely crash if I pass in a string that uses a format specifier other than `%@`.